# How to add a entity to collection inside another entity in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity

I have a two Entitys `Video`and `Comment`. 
One video can have many comments (OneToMany).

**Entity/Video.php**

```
class Video
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="videoId")
     */
    private $comments;

    /**
     * Set comments
     *
     * @param integer $comments
     * @return comments
     */
    public function setComments($comments)
    {
        $this->comments = $comments;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get comments
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getComments()
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

}
```

**Entity/Comment.php**

```
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Video")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="videoId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $videoId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $comment;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set videoId
     *
     * @param integer $videoId
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setVideoId($videoId)
    {
        $this->videoId = $videoId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get videoId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getVideoId()
    {
        return $this->getVideo($this->videoId);
    }

    /**
     * Set comment
     *
     * @param string $comment
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setComment($comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get comment
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getComment()
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }
}
```

---

**VideoEntity: id *PK***

**CommentEntity: videoId *FK***

---

I call the video in my controller like:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Video'); 
$video = $repository->findBy(array('id' => 1));
```

After this call, I have a filled video entity. 
But `video.comments` are not filled with the `comment` entity. 
It have only a integer.

Is it possible to fill the `video.comments` with the `comment` entity inside the `video` entity (video.id == comment.videoId)?

Example:

```
array
-- video entity
---- id
---- comments
------ array
-------- comment entity
---------- comment
-------- comment entity
---------- comment
-------- comment entity
---------- comment
```

I would be grateful for a best practice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to [`EAGER` load](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetomany) those comments:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment",fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="videoId")
 */
private $comments;
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity/Video.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="videoId")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="video_id")
 */
private $comments;
```

Entity/Comment.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Video")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="video_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $videoId;
```